# Remember login when connecting to another domain on Windows 2008 Sever

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, login

I run Windows 2008 Server (x64) as a workstation and my computer is on one domain and my exchange server, shared folders and intranet is on another domain.

Every time I connect to these eg. every time I open Outlook I am prompted to supply username and password in a "Connect to"-dialog and the "Remember password" option has no effect.

What can I do to avoid this manual step every time?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem and found no easy solution. I have no idea why remember password does not work, but I was messing around with various settings without luck.

After ages, the only solutions I could find were to use federated domain (which can be a nightmare to setup if you don't need to do anything else) or to connect Outlook to Exchange via alternative methods such as Outlook Anywhere with a saved password.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, if you synchronize your passwords you might be able to get it to work by using runas to run outlook with the other domains users credentials so create a shortcut for

```
runas /user:otherdomain\username "path\to\outlook"
```